# Angular JS Forgerock OIDC integration

Tags: angularjs, openid-connect, forgerock

We have to implement OAuth OIDC in Angular JS framework using Forgerock provided authentication mechanism. Before starting my questions are
1) Where the Authentication login/register screen will be dipslyed. Do we need to open it in iFrame or a popup window. 
2) How it could be integrated in Angular JS, what all additional libraries would be required and/or if any sample code is available.
3) How to capture the jwt token once the authentication is complete.

Comment: Does Forgerock not have any documenation for this?

Comment: Forgerock doesnt have any proper documentation available, they had recommended to use Passport.js however that works with Node.js which is server side language and needs Express framework as well.

Comment: Understood that in OIDC flow, no need to open a new window or iframe, the Authentication screen will be displayed in the same screen from where we are calling the Authentication and upon success registration/sign in redirect_uri will be returned to the same opened window.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will use ForgeRock's own login page - the most standard option is to redirect the whole page to ForgeRock
2. Forgerock provide very good support for standards so you should be able to use any standards based library. I would recommend [oidc client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) since it is mature and widely used.
3. The login response will contain an authorization code which you can swap for tokens.

I have some resources on integrating SPAs and APIs with an Authorization Server and you should be able to follow the same concepts in AngularJS:

1. Maybe run the SPA on my [quick start page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) to understand the **user experience** for Open Id Connect based logins
2. If you are new to this security model, have a look at my [initial tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/) to understand the endpoints and messages used

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Yes this is first time I am trying on a security model, I will follow provided link and try to achieve same.